# Is it possible to turn an <img> on webpage to base64 using FileReader?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, filereader

I already have
`var img = new Image();
img.src = src-url;`
How to pass it to a FileReader?
PS:I don't use canvas to get base64 because canvas same suppoert gif format.

Comment: remote images.is it possible?

Comment: check out http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/.

Comment: "remote images.is it possible". No. You will have to use server side proxy.

Comment: @dfsq If the image is on the same domain or the other domain is configured to support CORS. Yes it's possible by using the latest APIs.

Answer (score 1):

An example using latest [APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/), which is not compatible with old browsers.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/40ca36f062050220082cd8c46b377ab4?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
  var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: 'image/png'});
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    console.log(reader.result)
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
};

xhr.send();
```

Comment: yes,you're right.For chrome extension,it just allow CORS.Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Tom Just add the right permission to the manifest file, and Chrome will gladly make a cross-origin request for you. `"permissions": ["http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/*"]` for example.